# mmap'd memory model visibility/synchronization in java

Tags: java, performance, synchronization, shared-memory, java-memory-model

What differences are there (if any) between the regular java memory model for memory in the heap vs an mmap'd file accessed through a direct byte buffer?

Eg if I have multiple threads writing to the byte buffer, is there any special synchronization necessary to ensure that a reader thread will see all the changes?

Answer (score 0):

No difference. Yes, you have to have store synchronized-with edges between writers and the reader to ensure data is written to the buffer.